# return variable from scalar valued function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I have a scalar valued function `conv2unicode` which is linked to assembly `dvb2unicode`.

I have to remove the assembly function from the database and return the value *as it is* . conv2unicode is used in many procedures in the project. I have not worked with functions in sql server before.

Is there any way to return the variable **x** by the function [conv2unicode]

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[conv2unicode](@x [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS [nvarchar](4000) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [dvb2unicode].[UserDefinedFunctions].[Dvb2unicode]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just `RETURN` the variable like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[conv2unicode](@x [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS [nvarchar](4000) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
RETURN @x
```

Comment: showing error  Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure conv2unicode, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'RETURN'.